# what does 3'bzzz stands for in verilog?

Tags: verilog, hardware

I have the following code but I don’t know what the `3'bzzz` stands for:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module reg_tercer_estado(entrada,hab,salida);
input [2:0] entrada;
input hab;
output [2:0] salida;
reg [2:0] auxsalida;

always @(entrada)
begin
    case (hab)
    1'b0: auxsalida=entrada;
    1'b1: auxsalida=3'bzzz;
    endcase
end

assign salida=auxsalida;

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to “HDL Compiler for Verilog” manual, `3'bzzz` is 3-bit number, and `z` is a condition for *'disconnected'* or *'high impedance'*, and it's also is not synthesizable.

So, `3'bzzz` means a 3-bit value with all three bits in disconnected state.

Comment: One correction: `z` is synthesizable when declaring tri-state drivers. Example `assign salida = (hab==1'b0) ? entrada : 3'bzzz;`

Comment: Thank you, Greg. Frankly saying, answering this question was first time I ever looked at Verilog.